# Difference between Hand code and recorded scripts in Automation testing

Tags: testing, automation, coded-ui-tests

Please let me know the difference between the hand written code and recorded scripts in automation testing tools like coded ui or any other tools.
Regards,
Raj

Comment: What do you mean by `hand written code`? Unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

By 'hand-written' I'll assume you mean manually coded...

I can see a few reasons. Coding experience is brilliant. It will be a worthwhile investment if you code your own tests because you can learn a lot about the testing framework you are using (CodedUI, Selenium etc) but also the language you are using (Java, C#). Manually coding these tests, using built in framework methods, will serve you well and give you much more knowledge than an automatic play back tool would.

Automatic playback tools can produce horrific code. Code that is ugly, badly named, no best practices followed, and unreliable location methods.

Playback tools will simply use the most simple way to find an element. This is not always the best. A classic example is XPath.

Most notably, XPath is a powerful tool, it can get you any element you need (or at least, I've never found a situation where XPath *cannot* be used), but playback tool's will produce horrific XPath queries based purely on position...let's take an example.

You've got a page that has 100 feed items. You want to verify after a particular action a feed item is shown on this page, but not only is it shown but it is the **first** one. You cannot use ID's etc, because the markup is badly made and so you must use XPath.

A playback tool might make a very odd XPath like: `//div[1]/span[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[10]/[td[2]/a[text()='Test']`.

Looks weird, right?

This will work a few times, but what happens if the app gets another `tr` element shoved at the top of the table? Now, `tr[10]` **wont** be the element you want, it'll be `tr[11]`.

Through manual coding, you can account for this, you can put in logic to work around this. Playback tool's wont.

I **highly** recommend coding these tests yourself. You **do not** need a few years experience to do this, you **do not** need any prior programming degrees. You need *time*.

Playback tools will also be limited in what they can do...you want to take a screenshot when a test fails? I highly highly doubt a playback tool will do this, you'll need to put in logic yourself. However, *this isn't hard to do yourself*.

There might be a business reason too - playback tools can convert manual tests into automated tests faster, but they won't be reliable - you'll need to have time to dedicate to making them reliable and fast. Time that would better be spent coding them yourself in the first place.

Comment: Silly question. As far as maintenance of coded tests and trivial recording. which of the two is harder to maintain.